# GNOME disks messes up partitions

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, smart, gnome-disk-utility

My disk is partitioned like this:

[image: before]

Every time I run any command (mount, format, delete partition,...), I get this:

[image: after]

The actual disk layout itself is not affected: no problems in GParted or CLI. The problem persist until reboot (logout or lightdm restart does not help).

Tried:

1. reinstalling package
2. reinstalling again with dependencies
3. purging, then installing

All for naught.

Also, the app crashes when partitioning, SMART testing, or making images mid-way. It detects various SMART errors, all of them are false.

I am not dual-booting Windows.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. I suggest you [report it.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) It's *probably* a display bug within the program, but just in case it's more serious, you may want to avoid this program until the bug is fixed.

Comment: @RodSmith [There already is one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1641308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Rod Smith in the comments I found a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1641308)

Now we wait...

Comment: If you've got a Launchpad account, there should be a link near the top-left of the bug report that reads "This bug affects {n} people. Does this bug affect you?" Click it and select "Yes, it affects me" from the pop-up. This will increase the count of people affected by the bugs, which increases its "heat" value, which increases the odds that somebody will fix it. Providing useful diagnostics -- especially information requested by developers -- will also help.

Comment: @RodSmith That was the first thing I did. I also added a comment